# What sort of things I can test in my android project using JUnit

Tags: android, junit

I am a Developer working on Android platform.
But I am new to JUnit.
I want to know what sort of things I can test in my application using JUnit?

Android documentation says: 
*"You can use plain JUnit to test a class that doesn't call the Android API,"*

What does this mean?
Is it that I can test those parts of project which don't call methods from Android SDK.

I mean can I test A List View's behavior using JUnit by tracking the behavior of methods like
`getCount()`, `getView()`, `onItemselected()`, `onItemClicked()`, etc.

Comment: Look ate the [Activity Testing Tutorial](http://developer.android.com/tools/testing/activity_test.html)

Answer (score 2):

Using an integration testing tool (Robotium is the defacto choice at this point) will let you test a lot deeper, including inspecting your running application.

(Note, Robotium is also built on JUnit, but adds a lot more Android-specific power.)

Answer (score 1):

With JUnit you can test **units** of code ([**unit testing**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unit_testing)) that won't call the Android API. If you want to test a *ListView* you should check out [**integration testing**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integration_testing).

#### Practical case of a unit test

You have a method `public void rate(int stars);` which rate a certain object with *1* to *5* stars. A test you could write is:

- `testRate_withOutOfRangeInt_throwOutOfRangeException();`